# Custom FindAll - Neo4j / SpringData

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Assuming I have Surname as a @Param Unique *( is an Example... )*
How can I write a query with a dynamic surname in input @Param ?
in this case I am trying to make a customFindAll

```
 @Query("MATCH (n:User:`$surname`) return n ")
  Flux<UserEntity> customFindAll(@Param("surname") String surname);
```

This query doesnt work in spring-data , but this is what I'd like to have...

*( Please note that I don't need the findAll for Id , but another parameter, like in this case the surname.. )*

Answer (score 0):

ok this worked for me

```
MATCH (n:User) WHERE $surname IN labels(n) RETURN n
```